# Java file not being created on Windows Server

Tags: java

My application has to create a .db file in order to work. If this file does not exists my application creates it. However on some versions of Windows, for example Windows Server the file is never created. Also i am certain there are full read / write permission for this folder.

This is my code to create the file:

```
String databaseFileLocation = "";
String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
File myAppDir = new File(homeDir, ".someApp");

databaseFileLocation = "jdbc:sqlite:" + myAppDir + fileSeparator + "history_" + userID + ".db";

Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseFileLocation);
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
stat.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chatHistory (channelID, sender, message, recipient, time);");
```

It works on Win 7, Win XP Win Vista, etc. But on Win Server its not being created. Even though I've got permissions.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

**EDIT**

This is how I'm creating the dir:

```
        String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File myAppDir = new File(homeDir, ".someApp");

         // if the directory does not exist, create it
        if (!myAppDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + myAppDir);
            boolean result = myAppDir.mkdir();

            if (result) {
                System.out.println("DIR created");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens if `.someApp` directory does not exist?

Comment: `.someApp` is created on the first run. And ive manually checked permissions after it was created. Also for some reason other files are being saved there but not the `.db` file

Comment: Did you check if `.db` file type is a system file and is hidden by default, on Win Server?

Comment: `.db` is not hidden i can paste a empty file into the folder and i see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file can't be created, you should get an error. Check the error handling of your application.

If you don't get one, then the file probably was created but not where you expect it.

I suggest to add some logging to the code:

```
log.debug("path="+myAppDir.getAbsolutePath());
log.debug("url="+databaseFileLocation);
```

Alternatively, use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what your application is doing.